# Using Regex find only double curly braces word from text

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like this

```
Hello {{xyz}} how are {{abc}. I am {opq}} for your {{bpq}}.
```

from this text i want to find only `{{abc}` and `{opq}}` except `{{xyz}}` and `{{bpq}}`. what will be the regular expression for `php`.

I have tried this

```
preg_match_all("/\{{(.*?)\}}/", $mytext, $matches);
```

Comment: I dont know why down vote here. If does have any problem in my question should let me know in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in PHP with PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)` which is used to skip+fail a match in alternation.

```
{{[^{}]*}}(*SKIP)(*F)|{{[^{}]*}|{[^{}]*}}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4AFVb6/2)

**Alternatively**, you can also use a lookaround based regex:

```
{{[^{}]*}(?!})|(?<!{){[^{}]*}}
```

- `(?!})` is negative lookahead to fail the match if next char is }
- `(?<!})` is negative lookbehind to fail the match if previous char is {

Comment: I don't see a particular reason to downvote this answer.

Comment: Oh I see now, take a look: https://regex101.com/r/4AFVb6/1 you should replace `.*?` with `[^{}]*`